# Java class with Jquery Mobile application

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, dreamweaver

I am developing a mobile app in Dreamweaver and Phonegap using HTML CSS and JavaScript.

Now i want to add a java class (self made) which will just send sms to a specific phone number when executed.

How can i add this to my Dreamweaver project and pack with phone gap.

Answer (score -1):

Why not use the Phonegap Javascript API to send SMS instead...
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494803/JavaScript%20API#sms

Comment: what is the equivalent in jquery moblie 1.3.0.0

Comment: It is deprecated in new version

Comment: I see. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMS%20inbox_sent%20access and https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/SMSComposer look related, and following those instructions may act as a stopgap until the SMS functionality is (re)added to Phonegap mid 2012 Doesn't make your life easy though.